# How can i able to display "names" in json dat in select <option>?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using script as follows.. I need to print names in option to display..

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_category/",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(e) {
        console.log(e); 
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var o = new Option("option text"+i, "value"+i);
            /// jquerify the DOM object 'o' so we can use the html method
            $(o).html("e.name"+i);
            $(".selectpicker").append(o);
        }

        $(".selectpicker").selectpicker('refresh');

        vm.articles = e;
        console.log(vm);

    },
});
```

I am a beginner in js and does not have much knowknowlede.. Can anybody please help me to print the names in the above code.

My json data is as

```
[
    {"name": "Health care", "cat_id": 1
    {"name": "Education", "cat_id": 2
    {"name": "Bakery", "cat_id": 3
    {"name": "Software company", "cat_id": 4
    {"name": "Automobile", "cat_id": 5
    {"name": "Agriculture", "cat_id": 6
    {"name": "Marketing", "cat_id": 7
    {"name": "Multimedia", "cat_id": 8
    {"name": "Electrical Shop", "cat_id": 9
    {"name": "AutoTaxi", "cat_id": 10
    {"name": "Workshop", "cat_id": 11
    {"name": "Engineering Work", "cat_id": 12
    {"name": "Medical Shop", "cat_id": 13
    {"name": "Lathe", "cat_id": 14
    {"name": "Hotel", "cat_id": 15}
]
```

Comment: I'm removing the vue.js tag since the question has nothing to do with vue

Comment: ohk,,, but i am using vue js to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, there are missing some relevant parts(`HTML` code, `Bootstrap` files, etc), but I tried to replicate your issue and you can use `e[i].name` to get the names from the `json`. Also, you can use `Object.keys(e).length` to get the actual length of the `json` and parse it correctly:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get_all_category/",
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    //replaced i < 10 with i < Object.keys(e).length
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(e).length; i++) {
      var o = new Option(e[i].name, "value" + i);
      $(".selectpicker").append(o);
    }
    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker('refresh');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class='selectpicker'>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (var i = 0; i <= e.length; i++) {
        var o = new Option(e[i].name, "value"+i);
        $(".selectpicker").append(o);
    }
```